# SDL2 has a few files that have been replaced. What file has replaced SDL_mixer.h

Tags: sdl-2

Which file should I use instead of this file?

> SDL_mixer.h

Answer (score 0):

It's `<SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>` and it's a part of a plugin you can download here: https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/